# Will this algorithm generate all points on a circle with uniform probability?

Tags: probability, algorithms

Let's say the circle has a radius R.

Algorithm:

- Generate a random value `r` between $0$ and $R$.
- Generate a random value `theta` between $0$ and 2$\pi$

Then the random point will have cartesian coordinates `(r * cos(theta), r * sin(theta))`.

Can this be used to generate all points on a circle with radius `R` with equal probability?

Comment: You need to be more precise about what you are looking for.  See [Bertrand's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand_paradox_(probability))

Comment: @lulu I'm perfectly precise in what I'm looking for.

Comment: Also:  referring to a "random value" doesn't mean anything unless you specify the distribution you are thinking of.

Comment: Asserting that you are  being precise isn't the same as actually being precise.  Guessing that you meant to refer to uniform distributions throughout, then the resultant distribution on the disk is obviously not uniform.  For the unit circle, the area covered as $r$ varies from $0$ to $.1$ is $\pi\times .1^2\approx .000314$.  But the area covered as $r$ varies between $.9$ and $1$ is $\pi-\pi\times .9^2\approx .5969$

Comment: You say on a circle (constant R) but you seem to want in a circle (0 to R).

Answer (score 4):

There is no such thing as generating all elements of an uncountable set with equal probability. The probability to generate any given element is $0$. What you can do is to generate elements with uniform density. This density needs to be defined with respect to some measure. Typically, in subsets of $\mathbb R^n$, one assumes the standard measure. Your algorithm doesn’t generate points with respect to that measure: More of the area of the circle is at larger radii, so larger radii need to be more probable, but you’re generating all radii with equal probability.